# Sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} nx^{2n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I understand why $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} nx^{2n}$ converges on $(-1; 1)$, but I have no idea how to compute the sum. I was thinking about substituting $y=x^2$, or maybe using properties of binomial coefficients, but it seems useless here. Taking the integral will change the value, so I'm lost.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This question, or questions equivalent to it, has been asked and answered a dozen times on this site. I encourage you to search for those earlier appearances.

Answer (score 4):

A common trick is to differentiate series, and that seems to be a likely option here. (I say this because the series looks vaguely geometric, and we can differentiate geometric series term by term, which is a very nice property to have.)

---

Let's start with the basic series

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{2n} = \frac{1}{1-x^2}$$

on the premise that $|x|<1$; the above is a geometric series in ratio $x^2$. We start here because it is one we can easily find, and one that'll get us something similar to what we *want* to find on differentiation.

We then differentiate both sides w.r.t. $x$ and get

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2nx^{2n-1} = \frac{2x}{(1-x^2)^2}$$

Hence, halving both sides and then multiplying by $x$ again,

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{2n} = \frac{x^2}{(1-x^2)^2}$$

Comment: Nice.  Response could you use a brief mention of why, re uniform continuity, re power sums, the derivative of the sum is the sum of the derivatives.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
S &= \sum_{n \ge 1} nx^{2n}
\\
x^2 S &= \sum_{n \ge 1} nx^{2(n+1)} = \sum_{n \ge 2} (n-1) x^{2n}
\\
S - x^2 S &= x^2 + \sum_{n \ge 2} nx^{2n} - \sum_{n \ge 2} (n-1) x^{2n} = \sum_{n \ge 1} x^{2n}
\\
S &= \frac{1}{1-x^2} \sum_{n \ge 1} x^{2n}
= \frac{x^2}{(1-x^2)^2}.
\end{align}